# JavaScript Regex: How do I replace a comma with a newline that falls only within 2 curly brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with two JSON objects separated by a colon.

```
{"index" : {"_id" : 1}},{"item" : "Shoes", "amount" : 55.55}
```

I am wanting to replace the comma between },{ with a newline.

How do I go about doing this?

I tried the following:

```
mystring.replace(/\},\{/g,'\n')
```

However, this also replaced the curly brackets too, which I want to keep.

Comment: Well what did you try? SO is for helping; we don't write your code for you.

Comment: I tried mystring.replace(/\},\{/g,'\n') Although this also replaced the curly brackets too, which I want to keep.

Comment: @Hayden Replace with `'}\n{'`?

Comment: Geez, why didn't I think of that? So simple. I am just having one of those days.

Comment: Don't sweat it. Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one posted any answer I'm going to do so. Ivar already provided an answer above in the comments, but here is my take on it.  In case of whitespace, you should at least do this:

```
var s = '{"index" : {"_id" : 1}} , {"item" : "Shoes", "amount" : 55.55}'; // (note spaces added)
s.replace(/}[^,]*,[^{"]*{/, "},\n{");

Outputs:
"{"index" : {"_id" : 1}},
{"item" : "Shoes", "amount" : 55.55}"
```

It's a bit more forgiving of whitespace around the comma, just in case. ;)